# YouTube video overlaps on the HTML drop down menu

Tags: html, wordpress, youtube, overlap

I've just added a plugin for Wordpress that allows me to show my playlists from Youtube.

But the player covers the dropdown menu.

I've tried `&wmode=opaque` and `&wmode=transparent` but none of these works.

The player is embedded via iframe.

Is there another way to fix this?
http://www.kazuto.de/kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of your dropdown menus. The z-index CSS rule establishes the position on the z-axis of all positioned elements on a page.

On line 246 of style.css, add in

```
.menu li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
Haven't thought about using `z-index` because I never really used it ^^